# Azure TableEntity Flatten method not working for "Byte" data type

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

While trying to insert data object into `azure-storage-table`, `TableEntity.Flatten` is throwing below exception.

`System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Unsupported type : System.Byte encountered during conversion to EntityProperty.`

Data object contains `byte` property which is not supported. As I receive this data object from upstream, I am ending up with new `class`, copying all the properties while changing the `byte` property into `int`.

Is there any other better alternative to it?

Answer (score 2):

Byte array is a supported property but you are right that byte is not. The types that are supported are here, check the  method that does the conversion. https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Lib/Common/Table/EntityPropertyConverter.cs

A workaround could be to convert the byte property to byte array of a single element.  But I strongly reccomend you to open a bug in github to add byte support. It should be easy to add this.

Sent out a pull request to add  byte property support to Flatten/ConvertBack methods: 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/pull/537/files

While waiting above pull request to be merged into the SDK. I have gone ahead and updated the original nuget package I wrote to support byte type and IEnumerable properties, it is here: 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/ObjectFlattenerRecomposer/

You should be able to use that as well. the methods are the same Flattena dn ConvertBack but they support Byte and all other IEnumerable types.

Update: This is now fixed in latest in latest version of the SDK. You still need to use Flatten and ConvertBack methods but you would be able to write and read byte type properties using the latest version.

Comment: One extra note, in addition to these types in the link, also the complex property types (your custom classes etc.) are supported. These complex properties may also have their own complex properties etc., as long as their end node properties at the bottom of their object tree are one of these types in the link I sent above above, Flatten method would traverse and flatten the entire complex object, converting end node properties to EntityProperty so it can be written to table storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider converting byte to an int property in the same class, and mark the byte property with [IgnoreProperty] attribute.

```
public class MyEntity : TableEntity
{
    public int MyPropertyInt { get; set; }

    [IgnoreProperty]
    public byte MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return (byte)this.MyPropertyInt;
        }

        set
        {
            this.MyPropertyInt = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not using TableEntity, I am directly converting my data object into a DynamicTableEntity using Flatten method